# TensorFlow TensorRT Warning - Could not find TensorRT

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, cudnn

I'm encountering an issue with TensorFlow while using TensorRT. The warning message I receive is as follows:

`2023-07-28 16:27:20.817724: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT`

I have already tried installing TensorRT and its dependencies correctly on my system, but the issue persists. My setup includes TensorFlow and an NVIDIA GPU with compatible drivers.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to resolve this? Any guidance on troubleshooting and fixing this warning would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you have not installed already, try to install it via pip: `pip install tensorrt`

Strangely, simply installing it does not help on my side. As if the path it looks for has changed across versions. If installing does not help for you either, try:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path to your python libs>/tensorrt_libs/`

My bet is this will be enough. However, if you additionally run into a version compatibility issue (say *.so.7 vs *.so.8), you can circumvent in some cases by adding symlinks into the same `tensorrt_libs` directory.